# Angle Constructions

Tags: geometry

Over the numerous math tests I've taken, I have yet to understand what angle can be constructed and what cannot. From my understanding, 30, 45, 60, and 90 degree angles can be constructed. You can then use these angles and subtract or add them to create other angles like 15 or 75. Also, any angle can be bisected. Are there any other basic angle measures that can be constructed like 30, 45, etc.? So 82.5° is an angle measure
 that can be constructed because you can add 60+60+45 to get 165 and then bisect it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An additional important (compass and straightedge) constructible angle is the $36^\circ$ angle and its relatives, which come up in the construction of the regular pentagon.

Subtracting $36^\circ$ from $60^\circ$ and bisecting $3$ times gets us the $3^\circ$ angle. From this we conclude that every integer multiple of the $3^\circ$ angle is constructible. There are no other constructible angles with an integer number of degrees.

For a characterization of all the constructible angles, we first need to define the *Fermat primes*. Let $F_n=2^{2^n}+1$. If $F_n$ is prime, it is called a Fermat prime. There are only $5$ known Fermat primes, $3,5,17,257, 65537$.

Theorem: Let $x\ge 0$. The $x^\circ$ degree angle is constructible if and only if 
$$x=\frac{360q}{2^k P}$$
where $q$ and $k$ are non-negative integers and $P$ is a product (possibly empty) of *distinct* Fermat primes.